# How to get chrome extension crash event?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

**Is there any way to get a chrome extension crash event?**

I wrote a chrome extension, it may crash sometimes.

1. Are there any chrome apis or events related to extension crashes?
2. if no, how do you monitor extension crashes?

Comment: Which part of the extension crashes? If it's the background page, your the content script can establish a `port` connection to the background page and use port's onDisconnect event to detect the crash and at least display an alert etc. It'll work only on pages where the content script is injected, though.

Comment: It seems crash on background. i will try your suggest, thanks a lot .